# c# redirect (pipe) process output to another process

Tags: c#, .net, process, pipe

I am trying to run a process in c# using the Process class.

```
Process p1  = new process();
p1.startinfo.filename =  "xyz.exe";
p1.startinfo.arguments = //i am building it based on user's input.
p1.start();
```

So based on user input i am building the argument value. Now i have a case where i have to pipe the output of p1 to another process say grep. so i basically tried this

p1.startinfo.arguments = "-info |grep 1234" ;

what i intended is something like    xyz.exe -info|grep 1234

but this doesn't seem to work in .net .. I can actually create another process variable and run "grep" as a separate process.. But i was wondering if there is any way to do as iam trying out above..

Comment: I found this blog article which covers exactly this question: [Using piped output redirection on the Process/ProcessStartInfo classes...](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/02/27/81370.aspx)

Comment: If you don't want to use CMD, check out the [MedallionShell](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell) library. It makes process stream redirection (and other aspects of process management) much simpler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The much easier way would be to do just use cmd as your process.

```
Process test = new Process();
test.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
test.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C ""echo testing | grep test""";
test.Start();
```

You can capture the output or whatever else you want like any normal process then.  This was just a quick test I built, but it works outputting testing to the console so I would expect this would work for anything else you plan on doing with the piping.  If you want the command to stay open then use /K instead of /C and the window will not close once the process finishes.

Comment: I need to do the same thing without cmd on linux. How can I connect the StreamReader of the source process with the StreamWriter of the target process?

Comment: and how to do that in Linux? :)

Comment: How to do exactly the same with Linux :)

Comment: Basically for Linux you'd replace "cmd" with "bash -c". Resulting in something like           info.FileName = "/bin/bash"; info.Arguments = "-c \"top -bn1 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | sed 's/.*, *\\([0-9.]*\\)%* id.*/\\1/' \""; this example works getting me the free CPU %.