# Redirecting console output to another application

Tags: c#, console

So say I run my program:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
                           + @"\Console.exe";
proc.Start();
```

And then wish to output my console stream to this application, how would I go about doing so?
So say I have:

```
Console.WriteLine("HEY!");
```

I want that to show up in program that I ran's console. I know I have to redirect the output using

```
Console.SetOut(TextWriter);
```

But I have no idea how I would go about making it write to the other program.

I can see how I could do it if I were running my main program from Console.exe using RedirectStandardInput.. but that doesn't really help :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectStandardInput` makes Console.exe take its input from a stream which you can access in the main program. You can either write directly to that stream, or use SetOut to redirect console output there...

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
                       + @"\Console.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.Start();

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hello");

Console.SetOut(proc.StandardInput);
Console.WriteLine("World");
```

**EDIT**

It's possible that Console.exe doesn't cope well with having data piped into it rather than entered interactively. You could check this from the command line with something like

```
echo "Hello" | Console.exe
```

If that doesn't do what you expect, redirecting your program's output won't either. To test your program without worrying about the target program, you could try

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C ""more""";
```

If that displays the text that you write to it, then the problem is on the receiving end.

Comment: I have pretty much this exact code, yet it doesn't seem to want to actually output to the other program :\
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("t1");
for example doesn't seem to write, I've tried flushing it but nothing happens :(

Comment: @Blam: Edited with some other things to try

Comment: Eventually got it working, just had to change my Console.exe program, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectStandardInput` isn't the problem.  `Console` is the problem.

```
 StreamWriter myConsole = null;
if (redirect)
{
 Process proc = new Process(); 
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) 
                       + @"\Console.exe"; 
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 proc.Start(); 
 myConsole = myProcess.StandardInput;
 }
 else
    myConsole = Console.Out;
```

Then just use `myConsole` as you would `Console.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Process.StandardOutput and Process.StandardInput. Check out this article from MSDN, which may help point you into the right direction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

By the way, a much easier way to do what you are doing can be found here, as an accepted answer to a similar SO question: [c# redirect (pipe) process output to another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290747/c-redirect-pipe-process-output-to-another-process)