# The `Process` does not start with the special characters in the process argument

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg

I can run `FFmpeg.exe -i test.flv -f flv - | ffplay -i -` in the cmd, But I can't run it in the c# codes when "|" is in argument.

This code works :

```
  Process process = new Process();
  process process .StartInfo.FileName = "FFmpeg.exe";
  process process .StartInfo.Arguments =" -i test.flv "
  process .Start();
```

But this code is not working :

```
  Process process = new Process();
  process process .StartInfo.FileName = "FFmpeg.exe";
  process process .StartInfo.Arguments =" -i test.flv -f flv - | ffplay -i -"
  process .Start();
```

I tried this codes but did not effect:

```
   process process .StartInfo.Arguments =" -i test.flv -f flv - \| ffplay -i -"

   process process .StartInfo.Arguments =" -i test.flv -f flv - \\| ffplay -i -"

   process process .StartInfo.Arguments =@" -i test.flv -f flv - | ffplay -i -"

   process process .StartInfo.Arguments ="\" -i test.flv -f flv - \| ffplay -i -\""
```

Please tell me how can I run `FFmpeg.exe -i test.flv -f flv - | ffplay -i -` in the C# codes.

Comment: what's the error you're getting ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# redirect (pipe) process output to another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290747/c-sharp-redirect-pipe-process-output-to-another-process)

Comment: The process does not start without any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piping the output from one command to another is a feature of the shell in which you execute those commands. In .NET, using the `Process` class you need to use a shell (usually `cmd.exe`) to achieve the same effect.

```
// usually expands to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%COMSPEC%"); 
// Build a command line passed to CMD.EXE
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C FFmpeg.exe -i test.flv -f flv - | ffplay -i -"
```

Additionally, depending on your use case, you normally want to wait for the process to finish:

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

And possible evaluate the exit code

```
if (process.ExitCode != 0) // Convention only! Usually, an exit of 0 means error. YMMV.
```

Finally, note that for pipelines, the exit code returned here is the exit code of the last command (in your case `ffplay`).