# C# Read User's Input, Generate Output, Process it through Pipe, if provided by user

Tags: c#

The following challenge: my C# app consumes user's input via Console.ReadLine() in order to generate an output (Console.WriteLine()) based on it, and returns back to the prompt line for further requests.

However, I consider also the use case, which implies that user would process the generated output through a pipe (e.g. to MORE), in order to comfortably read the output, and would return to the prompt afterwards.

How could I elegantly achieve it w/ C#, without starting a sub-Process in a new terminal?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you need a new process? Sounds like you need a mechanism for the user to provide all input up front so the process can run unattended.

Comment: the only possibility I see so far, is to start a new process w/ a Process class similar as proposed here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290747/c-sharp-redirect-pipe-process-output-to-another-process
I would appreciate any ideas, how it could be made natively w/o a new sub-process in a way like this:
read user's input -> generate output -> if pipe has been provided ( <input> | more) -> show output in MORE -> return to prompt after more is closed

Comment: Just write to standard output - `MORE` will consume it just fine.

Comment: here is the thing: the app produces the output based on the user's input. Should I implement a System.IO.Pipe interface in order to forward a produced output to the desired process piped by the user internally?

Comment: Do you have an example, how it could look like?